# Are vb.net class attributes inherited?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, attributes

Are the attributes of a class inherited by a derived class or do they have to be applied specifically to the derived class?

E.g. for system.timer.timer:

```
'Declaration
<HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Synchronization := True,  _
    ExternalThreading := True)> _
Public Class Timer _
    Inherits Component _
    Implements ISupportInitialize
```

If I then have a class

```
Class MyScheduler
    Inherits Timer
    '...
End Class
```

Do I need to explicitly apply the attributes of the timer calss to the MyScheduler class or does that happen as part of the inheriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default attributes are not inherited, but you can make them inheritable by using the `Inherited:=True` syntax on the attribute, like this:

```
<HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Synchronization := True,  _
ExternalThreading := True, Inherited:=True)> _
Public Class Timer _
    Inherits Component _
    Implements ISupportInitialize
```

Now any class derived from `Timer` will also have the attributes of the `Timer` class applied to it with the sub-class attributes overriding any conflicts between the two.

Comment: Thanks, that answers. But can I add to system defined classes? If I "go to definition" of timer I get the object browser instead of modifiable code.

Comment: @Toby - you would need to modify the source of the .NET Framework and then recompile it.